# What do I need to know to do this kind of animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have an idea for android game, but since I am still a beginner in Android development especially animations and I don't know where to begin. Can somebody direct me at the right direction, please. I want to do the similar animation such as the jump animations in this game: [image]

Comment: For this you'll need some time (some years) of experience in game development.

Comment: Game development and Android (native) development have little in common. Consider taking Design and Game Development courses to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked. This game is using [OpenGL](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/) (which is not easy to learn).

Even the jelly cube has a slight 3D perspective to it.

One shortcut would be to use [Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

A second shortcut would be to buy/license some of the 3D models you want to use in your own game. There are several web marketplaces that specialize in selling stuff like that.

A third shortcut would to try to replicate the same effect in a 2D environment. It won't look as good, but you can still make a decent game even in 2D.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping that it will be easy to implement. However, Unity sounds good :)